# Get health status for several services via one request in consul.io

Tags: consul

There is [method (/v1/health/service/)](http://www.consul.io/docs/agent/http/health.html#health_service) for one service. But i need periodically check state of several services. Now I have to send several HTTP requests for this.

Is it possible to check state of services by passing array of names or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

Unless the services you want to monitor are in fact the same service (meaning 2 instances of your "webserver" service for example) I do not believe this to be possible in one API call.

Maybe you can make use of the [watches](https://consul.io/docs/agent/watches.html) functionality to monitor the healthcheck status of your services? Thus making your system more push oriented instead of pull?

Comment: I want to monitor 3+ different services with dif names. But, I will check watches functionality. Mb it's good solution.